# The import com.activiti.domain.idm.User cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, runtime-error, activiti

Good morning,

I'm trying to make an Activiti process with Eclipse, and try to import some librairy, but I have the error "The import com.activiti.domain.idm.User cannot be resolved"

I tried to download some .jar files that I find, but no one are working, I wanted to know how can I find this import to resolve my error

Thank you in advance

Comment: could be please provide more info - what version of activiti are you using? enterprise ot community?

Comment: I use Activiti 6.0

Comment: But I found another solution by following this process https://www.baeldung.com/java-activiti. I just begin looking at so i'm a not sure it work very good, but i'm trying